# What is the difference between $("selection") and $("selection", $(this))

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I have seen the use of $(this) and understand within the function, but also have seen in a selector as well, but fail to understand when or if it is valuable. Here are two examples I can use and get to work, but am I really doing anything valuable...

Here I added $(this) in selectors

```
(function($) {
    $(".deliver").on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).css({'width':'600px'});
        $(".form_jquery",$(this)).fadeIn(1000).css({'display':'block'});
        $(".componentheading",$(this)).css({'display':'none'});
    }); ...
```

Here is my original script

```
(function($) {
    $(".deliver").on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).css({'width':'600px'});
        $(".form_jquery").fadeIn(1000).css({'display':'block'});
        $(".componentheading").css({'display':'none'});
    });
```

I have kept what I know as the standard use of (this) in both and noting that I am using in a anonymous function in case this factors in.

Comment: `$('selector',this)` or `$('selector',$(this))` is equivalent to `$(this).find('selector')` -- 'this' is a *context* for the selector. http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1

Comment: @Blazemonger, it even uses it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".componentheading",$(this))
```

only searches the `.componentheading` elements under the current `$(this)` element (in this particular case it's a `.deliver` which you entered the mouse) whereas

```
$(".componentheading")
```

searches them in the whole document.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Answer (score 0):

Providing a second argument to the jQuery function narrows the context of the selection. By default, the context is the entire document.

In the case of using `$(this)` as a context, you are only looking for elements with the `form_jquery` or `componentheading` classes *inside of* the element triggering the `mouseenter` handler.

Providing a context to narrow the selector searches is a good way to improve your selector performance, as long as you know that the element you're looking for can indeed be found in that context.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( selector, context )
```

The actual function for jQuery looks like this `jQuery( selector, context )`, if you provide an element for the context value, when jQuery tries to `jQuery.find` your element, it will start with element you provided.

In many cases this can provide a performance boost!

[**Read about jQuery Context**](http://api.jquery.com/context/)

To supply an element to the jQuery function, a lot of people employ a method called [DOM caching](http://misteroneill.com/journal/jquery-dom-cache/) where you store the element in a variable and pass it to the jQuery function as the referencing context.